# Keeping a Node JS Application running

Tags: node.js, bash, while-loop

I have the following file:
reload.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do 
    $("node bot.js &")
    sleep 1000
done
```

But it doesn't open the JavaScript using node, it just errors until it runs out of memory and kills itself. I'm fairly new to bash and looking for a quick fix to keep it running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`forever`](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) npm module, it ensures the script stays running and has a lot of features which are the next things you will look for past simply running the script.

Install `forever`

```
npm install -g forever
```

Then run the script

```
forever start bot.js
```

Forever allows you to start/stop/restart the process and manage logs and pid files.

It also has a node API that allows you to manage processes from your javascript, if needed.

**Alternate NPM Modules**

[pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) is production process management tool.
[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) can monitor files and restart the process for you during development.